# Remote access over VPN machine

Tags: vpn

Here is my scenario. I have Comp1 which has VPN installed on it & working fine. I have made Comp1 as remote enabled as well. Now i want to log in to Comp1 ( remotely) from Comp2.

Without starting the VPN, remote desktop works fine from Comp2 to Comp1. When i connect to VPN on Comp1 the remote desktop from Comp2 breaks.

Is there a way i can run VPN on Comp1 and be able to access from Comp2 remotely.

If there is change in settings, please advice.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like your vpn administrator has disabled [split-tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).  

What vpn are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing by involving a 3rd computer.  For example:

I'm at a remote location to set up a tunnel back to the corporate network.  I need to get on the corporate network to set up the other end of the tunnel.  I VNC (or RDP) to a computer at my house.  If I used the computer at my house to connect to the corporate VPN at this point, I'd knock myself out of the VNC connection.

Instead, while remoted into the home computer, I VNC yet again to another computer at my house (meaning, this VNC connection is through the LAN, and not subject to the VPN) and use this second house computer to establish the VPN to corporate.

So, in your scenario, from Comp2, RDP into Comp3 (on same LAN is Comp1), and from Comp3, RDP into Comp1.  Now, from Comp1, start your VPN connection.  You are now connected to the VPN by way of Comp1, through Comp3, from Comp2 lol.  Convoluted I know, but it works in a pinch.